# Adding <p> to a <div> inside a <div> container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying add some text to a child div. When I include a `<p>` inside the div the whole thing screws up.

Why does the `<p>` element cause what is depicted in the image below?

**Before Adding the Text:**

[image: Before adding the text]

**After Adding the Text:**

[image: After adding the text]

```css
.containerDonation {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
.donations {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
.donateCircle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22%;
  height: 275px;
  border: 4px solid #99CCFF;
  border-radius: 250px;
  margin: 10px 40px 0px 40px;
}
.donate {
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
}
.donate p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="containerDonation">
  <div class="donations">
    <div class="donateCircle">
      <div class="donate">
        <p>Small Donation</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="donateCircle">
      <div class="donate">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="donateCircle">
      <div class="donate">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what is your html and css ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just adding screenshots are not helpful, add complete and relevant code in the question. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Are you able to provide code snippet with all the details please? The <p> tag by default has margins..

Comment: I've added your screenshots directly to the question and cleaned up your CSS/HTML code. Voting to reopen. Thanks for reading the documentation and updating your question accordingly.

Comment: adding `display: inline-block` to the `<p>` tag css should fix it

Comment: Add this in your css: `.donateCircle { ... /* existing css values */ ... vertical-align: top; }`. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/ph70brpw/) for a working example. **Note:** Because jsfiddle operates in a reduced size iframe, the circles appear distorted. However, removing the `vertical-align` value above accurately demonstrates the problem and solution from your screenshots above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `vertical-align` your `.donateCircle` divs:

```css
.containerDonation {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 4px solid black;
}

.donations {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    border: 4px solid red;
}

.donateCircle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22%;
    height: 275px;
    border: 4px solid #99CCFF;
    border-radius: 250px;
    margin: 10px 40px 0px 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.donate {
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 175px;
    width: 175px;
}

.donate p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="containerDonation">
    <div class="donations">
        <div class="donateCircle">
            <div class="donate">
                <p>Small Donation</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="donateCircle">
            <div class="donate">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="donateCircle">
            <div class="donate">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Note:** that due to the `width` values using percentages, and the snippet being run in an `<iframe>` the content looks off. The `vertical-align` principle applies non the less though and can be viewed using the snippets <kbd>Full Screen</kbd> option or by visiting the [full screen link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360670/adding-p-to-a-div-inside-a-div-container/34361370#34361370).

Answer (score 1):

The default vertical alignment of inline elements is `baseline`, so you need to change that to top in order for them to all be top aligned. Add `vertical-align:top` to `.donateCircle`:

```css
.containerDonation {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
.donations {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
.donateCircle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22%;
  height: 275px;
  border: 4px solid #99CCFF;
  border-radius: 250px;
  margin: 10px 40px 0px 40px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.donate {
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
}
.donate p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="containerDonation">
  <div class="donations">
    <div class="donateCircle">
      <div class="donate">
        <p>Small Donation</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="donateCircle">
      <div class="donate">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="donateCircle">
      <div class="donate">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```